# Create tabs in tabularx environment

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx

I just have a question if it's possible to insert tabs into one cell in `tabularx`. For a better illustration of this problem I will include pictures.

[image: TextBox text]

This is what I have in textbox in my program. So I can determine where the tab keys, newlines and spaces are. I need same format in cell in `tabularx`. In LaTeX code I have this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{lX}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Identification:}} \\
\textbf{End A:} & Something \newline Wire 1: asd Color: black Type: copper \newline Wire 2: asd Color: red Type: aluminium \\
\textbf{End B:} &  \\
\end{tabularx}
```

[image: Latex output]

But I need to have the same spacing like in textbox. Is there any possibility how to do it? Because I really dont want to create as many columns as I need for it and then multicolumn those which are not used. Maybe something similar as \> in `tabbing`.

Comment: Why not just use extra columns to identify the tab points (see [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iQwnb.png))?

Comment: Maybe I dont uderstand what you mean. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a tabular-like alignment, insert columns to suit your needs:

[image: tabular]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lll@{\quad}ll@{\quad}ll}
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Identification:}} \\
  \textbf{End A:} & Something \\
    & Wire 1: asd & Color: black & Type: copper \\
    & Wire 2: asd & Color: red   & Type: aluminium \\
  \textbf{End B:} & Something else \\
    & Wire 1: qwe    & Color: green  & Type: silver \\
    & Wire 2: qwerty & Color: yellow & Type: gold
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If need be, this process can be automated. For example, if you always have `Wire X:` in the first column, `Color:` in the second and `Type:` in the third. It can also be turned into a macro that arranges them accordingly, avoiding you to repeatedly use the alignment operators `&`.

---

Alternatively, use a `tabbing` environment with a number of predefined tabs. You may not use all of them, but that's not a problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{tabenv}[1][7em]
  {\begin{tabbing}
   \hspace*{#1}\=\hspace{#1}\=\hspace*{#1}\=\hspace*{#1}\=\hspace*{#1}\=\hspace*{#1}\=\kill}
  {\end{tabbing}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabenv}
  \textbf{Identification:} \\
  \textbf{End A:} \> Something \\
    \> Wire 1: asd \> Color: black \> Type: copper \\
    \> Wire 2: asd \> Color: red   \> Type: aluminium \\
  \textbf{End B:} \> Something else \\
    \> Wire 1: qwe    \> Color: green  \> Type: silver \\
    \> Wire 2: qwerty \> Color: yellow \> Type: gold
\end{tabenv}

\noindent
\begin{tabenv}[8em]
  \textbf{Identification:} \\
  \textbf{End A:} \> Something \\
    \> Wire 1: asd \> Color: black \> Type: copper \\
    \> Wire 2: asd \> Color: red   \> Type: aluminium \\
  \textbf{End B:} \> Something else \\
    \> Wire 1: qwe    \> Color: green  \> Type: silver \\
    \> Wire 2: qwerty \> Color: yellow \> Type: gold
\end{tabenv}
\end{document}
```

The optional argument supplied to the `tabenv` environment defines the spaces of the tabs (default is `7em`).

---

Another alternative that treats the list of items like a regular list, putting each in a box of prespecified width, which allows them to wrap to subsequent lines. The list processing is done using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) (other list processing packages will be able to do the same thing), while the tabular arrangement is kept using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) so as to fill the entire `\linewidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{etoolbox,tabularx}
\newlength{\textboxlen}
\newenvironment{tabenv}[1][7em]
  {\setlength{\textboxlen}{#1}%
   \tabularx{\linewidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
  {\endtabularx}
\newcommand{\items}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{% Each item will be put in a...
    \makebox[\textboxlen][l]{##1}\hspace{0pt}}% ... box
  \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabenv}
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Identification:}} \\
  \textbf{End A:} & Something \\
    & \items{Wire 1: asd, Color: black, Type: copper} \\
    & \items{Wire 2: asd, Color: red, Type: aluminium} \\
  \textbf{End B:} & Something else \\
    & \items{Wire 1: qwe, Color: green, Type: silver} \\
    & \items{Wire 2: qwerty, Color: yellow, Type: gold}
\end{tabenv}

\noindent
\begin{tabenv}[8em]
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Identification:}} \\
  \textbf{End A:} & Something \\
    & \items{Wire 1: asd, Color: black, Type: copper} \\
    & \items{Wire 2: asd, Color: red, Type: aluminium} \\
  \textbf{End B:} & Something else \\
    & \items{Wire 1: qwe, Color: green, Type: silver} \\
    & \items{Wire 2: qwerty, Color: yellow, Type: gold, Stuff: apples, Things: baking, Money: Twelve}
\end{tabenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be good solution but problem is that it should not be the same all the time. I mean that the user can hit tabular many times to do more spaces so you dont know how many columns you will need. I can calculate them but I wanted some better solution to create tabular with float columns. Also what mean @{} in columns?

Comment: @MichalJurčík: I've added a `tabbing` alternative. You can prespecify a number of tab positions, even though you might not use them all. `@{<stuff>}` is used to identify the intercolumn spacing in a `tabular`.

Comment: Perfect and last thing i need to wrap text automatically is it possible? Because the line can be long.

Comment: @MichalJurčík: I've updated the solution to now provide a list-style interface using `\items{<item1>,<item2>,...}` that should wrap if needed.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed many thanks. But quiet difficult for me.

Comment: Okey. But I found one last problem. The text will not wrap if the item text is too long also it wont accept ',' in text. Is there possibility to fix it?

Comment: @MichalJurčík: Circumventing the inclusion of `,` requires you to wrap the item in braces: `\items{...,{..,..},...}`. With all these additional requirements, do you really need tabs to make things align?

Comment: Its quiet difficult because its much easier to do it in latex then parsing it in my program. A just wanna has an output same like in program. Typing a tab key in textbox create spaces depending on position in text array. If you hit tab the formula is (8 - (position % 8)) spaces and if the char before is also tab key it puts 8 spaces.